# How does Rust's struct hold and use a object?

Tags: rust

I need to use a struct to hold a serde_json object, and use it later.

```
extern crate serde_json;

use serde_json::builder::ObjectBuilder;

struct MyStruct {
    builder: ObjectBuilder,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct { builder: ObjectBuilder::new() }
    }

    fn add_string_member(&self, name: &str,  value: &str) {
        self.builder.insert(name, value); //here compile error
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct::new();
    s.add_string_member("name", "value");
}
```

But I get the error

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
```

Comment: My foo might be off.. but I don't think this is the error you're getting. You're more likely to get a `cannot borrow 'builder' as mutable` error. Is this the exact error and line number? You appear to be mutating a field on the `MyStruct` instance with an immutable reference.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Oh, he's probably getting quite a few error given the signature of the methods in [ObjectBuilder](http://serde-rs.github.io/json/serde_json/builder/struct.ObjectBuilder.html), they take *everything* by value :)

Comment: .... i check the serde_json souce code, it use self not &self.... so i just change &self to self should be ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods in [`ObjectBuilder`](https://serde-rs.github.io/json/serde_json/builder/struct.ObjectBuilder.html) take `self` by value. Since you can't move something out of a borrowed pointer, the easy solution is to make your methods on `MyStruct` take `self` by value as well.

Also, `ObjectBuilder`'s methods return a new `ObjectBuilder` with the changes. You can wrap that return value into a new `MyStruct`, which you can return from your methods.

```
extern crate serde_json;

use serde_json::builder::ObjectBuilder;

struct MyStruct {
    builder: ObjectBuilder,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct { builder: ObjectBuilder::new() }
    }

    fn add_string_member(self, name: &str, value: &str) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct { builder: self.builder.insert(name, value) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct::new();
    let s = s.add_string_member("name", "value");
}
```

If `MyStruct` also contains other members that you'd like to carry on into the new `MyStruct`, you can use a shortcut syntax to initialize the remaining fields of `MyStruct` from an existing instance:

```
fn add_string_member(self, name: &str, value: &str) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct { builder: self.builder.insert(name, value), ..self }
}
```

Here, the `builder` field of the new `MyStruct` will be set to the specified expression, and all other fields will be moved from `self`. (The `..` syntax accepts any expression of the proper type, not just `self`.)